# "A better student" or "Better a student"?

Tags: word-usage

I want to know if it's grammatically correct to make a comparative sentence with the word "Better" like this: "I'm better a student than you" instead of this: "I'm the better student than you are"

Comment: Neither of these are grammatically correct. You could say "I'm a better student than you", "I'm a better student than you are" or "I'm the better student".

Comment: @TimFoster hmm, I think it's borderline correct, so I checked and found this snippet: [*You are **better a man** than he will ever be, more handsome, more firm and you have the wisdom of the Gods.*](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1309&bih=647&tbm=bks&ei=0mjUXIfkM4a6kwWlvYOABQ&q=He%27s+%22better+a+man+than%22&oq=He%27s+%22better+a+man+than%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3432.7786.0.8102.4.4.0.0.0.0.76.288.4.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.diXbrUfCoqI)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Oh interesting, never seen that before, except after "no". Still, I dare say this is pretty much limited to literary usage in modern English.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Yes, "I'm better a student than you'll ever be" works, but I don't think "I'm better a student than you" works. // Kien, you can fix the second sentence like this: "I'm the better student than you."

Comment: @aparente001 *I'm the better student than you* ? Really? For me it's *of the two of us, I'm the better student* or *I'm a better student than you*.